# Entity-framework ObjectContext и DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Читаю книгу. Дошел до Entity-framework-а. И получается такая проблема. В книги класс который получается после создания элемента Entity-framework наследуется от `ObjectContext`

```
public partial class AutoLog1Entities : ObjectContext
```

А когда я создаю новый элемент Entity-framework и автоматические заполняю его данными с таблицы, то мой класс почему-то становится наследником `DbContext`

```
public partial class AutoLog1Entities : DbContext
```

Следовательно не могу ни чего сделать. Так как методы, которые есть в `ObjectContext` отсутствуют в `DbContext`. Я так понял, что это зависит от версии EF (но это не точно), но не могу найти версию, которая использует `ObjectContext` вместо `DbContext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начиная с версии 4.1
`DbContext` это аналог `ОbjectContext`, по функционалу они почти идентичны. Разница в работе с ними конечно есть и проще будет пересоздать проект под старую версию, если хотите следовать книге.

Более подробно можно почитать в статьях: 
[Статья #1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ff2f08/objectcontext-vs-dbcontext/)
[Статья #2](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/accessing-objectcontext-features-from-ef-4-1-dbcontext/)

Comment: Они "почти" идентичны только с виду, внутри у них отличия довольно серьезные.

Comment: Главным образом, отличается поведение рекурсивного обхода при добавлении элементов к навигационным коллекциям.